# PDFs produced by R having inconsistent MD5 checksum

Tags: r, pdf, plot, graphics, metadata

I'm testing an R package using **testthat**. Writing tests for an S3 method `plot.foo` is a huge headache, because it simply returns `NULL`, so I decided to save the plot to a file and check if it has been changed since the last run.

```
pdf(file='plot_foo.pdf')
plot.foo(bar)
dev.off()
tools::md5sum('plot_foo.pdf')
```

The problem is each time I'm getting a different result with the same input. The output looks the same, though.

```
replicate(10, {
  pdf(file='plot.pdf')
  plot(1:10, 10:1)
  dev.off()
  Sys.sleep(1)
  tools::md5sum('plot.pdf')
})
```

Note that you need to wait a while between each iteration, otherwise the file would be identical, which makes me suspect some time-based metadata is changed.

```
                          plot.pdf                           plot.pdf
"5a0c096fe088342bc3c3d5960c5da1c9" "40d93c26b4901aef55a32b75473d05d2"
                          plot.pdf                           plot.pdf
"9815c6d9b2e94cda763a486fcd2ddf08" "a8e8db82d06b79f98416fa034b5aee46"
                          plot.pdf                           plot.pdf
"c2770250dbef3b60706559114c434851" "91c8cf124eb61ddebd3edbbb2d01677f"
                          plot.pdf                           plot.pdf
"d1594bd83b97fc890410a4c305366682" "f05197f165ec04df3dac4664494f4617"
                          plot.pdf                           plot.pdf
"64427124c6a6454e8f0e5944de20be95" "ff1abf2b31dfe688cf8f5994e409cc6d"
```

How do I force R to produce consistent PDFs? I'm temporary switching to PostScript for testing purposes, but I'd prefer PDF as it's better-supported (Windows doesn't seem to have a builtin PostScript viewer) and thus can also serve as the document.

Comment: Have you tried look at diffs between the different PDFs to see what's changing?

Comment: I think PDFs often have a `CreatedDate` metadata within it. On a file I generated recently, I did `pdftk myfile.pdf dump_data` and see that it has a timestamp in it. I suspect that using the checksum will always be sensitive to negligible differences like this.

Comment: Yep I have just done some checking (using this method: https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux) and it looks like there are 1 or 2 timestamps in each file that end up differing, and there's no obvious way to disable timestamps in `pdf()`.

Comment: For testing, you can save the plots as PNG files (or convert the PDF to PNG).

Comment: Check out [`vdiffr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vdiffr/index.html). From its description: *"Visual Regression Testing and Graphical Diffing: An extension to the 'testthat' package that makes it easy to add graphical unit tests. It provides a Shiny application to manage the test cases."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think it's a little rough on a few things, I think `vdiffr` is going to let you do what you need.

1. First, I'm going to create a package; fake for now, but necessary, since `vdiffr` only works in a tightly-controlled environment: a package using `testthat`.

   ```r
   usethis::create_package("~/StackOverflow/nalzok")
   setwd("~/StackOverflow/nalzok")
   usethis::use_testthat()
   ```
2. Create a `test_something.R` test file.

   ```r
   context("basic plot tests")
   baseplot1 <- function() hist(1:10)
   vdiffr::expect_doppelganger("base 1", baseplot1)
   ```

   (I'm going to assume that `hist(1:10)` is something relevant and interesting. Base plots need to be a function, `ggplot2` objects do not; see the docs for more.)
3. I had thought I could call `vdiffr::expect_doppelganger` directly (as most `testthat::expect_*` functions often can be), but it needs to be "managed" (setup) first.

   ```r
   vdiffr::manage_cases(".")
   ```

   Each of the images need to be "verified" (by a human), so this opens a shiny app that iterates through each of the expected doppelgangers:

   [image: shiny app for image-validation]
4. After validation, each time you `test` the package, it will verify that the images have not changed:

   ```r
   devtools::test()
   # Loading nalzok
   # Testing nalzok
   # v | OK F W S | Context
   # v |  1       | basic plot tests
   # == Results =====================================================================
   # OK:       1
   # Failed:   0
   # Warnings: 0
   # Skipped:  0
   ```
5. If something changes (perhaps changing the `hist(1:10)` to `hist(2:11)`), it'll fail the next test:

   ```r
   devtools::test()
   # Loading nalzok
   # Testing nalzok
   # v | OK F W S | Context
   # x |  0 1     | basic plot tests
   # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # test_something.R:3: failure: (unknown)
   # Figures don't match: base-1.svg
   # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # == Results =====================================================================
   # OK:       0
   # Failed:   1
   # Warnings: 0
   # Skipped:  0
   ```

   It does this by creating a `./tests/testthat/figs/` directory with a directory and `.svg` file for each expectation, and while you don't need to interact with it, it would make sense for `.../figs/` to be version-controlled (you *do* version-control you package, right?).

Some caveats, I guess:

- it is saving to `.svg` files; if your S3 `plot.foo` function doesn't play well with SVG (does that happen? I don't know), then I don't know (yet) how to deal with that;
- since it's using the text-based SVG format, it will notice if a point or box or something shifts, but only within some basic tolerances; as an example, if even some meta-parameters (limits) are changed *sufficiently*, it will trigger a failure. This is generally good, since I believe the test should be resilient to minor changes (upstream library, etc).

  ```r
  hist(1:10)                    # pass
  hist(1:10, xlim=c(0,10))      # pass, that's the default x-limit given the data
  hist(1:10, xlim=c(0,10+1e-5)) # pass, close enough?
  hist(1:10, xlim=c(0,10+1e-4)) # FAIL
  ```